# Can a single point on the real line be isolated under any metric space?

Tags: measure-theory

My shaky understanding is that whether a single point in a set can be [isolated](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point) depends on whether a radius can be defined around the point, such that no other point in the set is included in the disc, ball or sphere thus defined.

Is it correct, then, to say that for points on the real line any radius will necessarily include adjacent points, and hence there can't be isolated points?

Comment: You can always take the discrete metric, so that every points are isolated.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: The discrete metric is $$d(x, y) = \begin{cases}  0 & \text{when } x=y \\ 1 & \text{if } x\neq y.\end{cases}$$ under this metric all balls with radius $<1$ has only one point.

Comment: OK... So we just have to declare a radius of less than one, and by this... rather whimsical measure, we have [balls with only one point](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/673068/152225).

Comment: And a radius of $1$ would collapse into one single ball the entire real line, like a mathematic magnetar?